# wordpress function custom field data convert to table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have numerous custom fields on my website that I want to be displayed in a table format, the custom field data looks like the following

Thiamin (as thiamin mononitrate);50 mg;3333% Vitamin B6 (as pyridoxine HCl);50 mg;2500% Magnesium (as magnesium bis-glycinate);150 mg;38% Manganese (as manganese citrate);5 mg;250% Malic Acid;600 mg;*

Instead I want this in table format is there some css or wordpress filter I could use to convert this data to a neatly displayed table

Comment: where is the code ???

Comment: thats is a example of the data in the standard wordpress custom fields, displaying it on the front end is no problem but formating it into a neat table is the problem